# "conda env list" is not pointing the current working environment in jupyter lab

Tags: conda, anaconda3

I have created a environment called "test" in anaconda prompt. I have started working in that environment. When I run the command "conda env list" in jupyter, it is not pointing my test environment where I am currently working.

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /anaconda
azureml_py36             /anaconda/envs/azureml_py36
test                     /anaconda/envs/test


Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Does any one know how to solve this?

Comment: After creating the environment, did you activate it? E.g., `conda activate test`

Comment: @merv yes,  i did that.  Even after running the command conda is still pointing the base environment.